# AWS Lambda function for URL masking

Tags: lambda, amazon-cloudfront, url-masking, vanity-url

I have a vanity URL that I want to redirect to a specific page in a website(Cloudfront Distribution). I can do a redirect with Masking from GoDaddy but it does not help me with https options for the vanity URL. So I was thinking of doing this using Lambda function triggered on Viewer Request section of the CF distribution. I am using the following code for the Lambda function, can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong as I am getting an error from CF side-

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
  response = {
    'status': '301',
    'statusDescription': 'Moved Permanently',
    'headers': {
        'location': [{
            'key': 'Location',
            'value': 'https://cf-distribution/page/'
        }]
      }
   }
  return response
```

I tried this lambda Function and was expecting it to redirect with masking to the page in CF distribution but it gives me an error, will post the error soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend CloudFront Functions over Lambda@Edge: it's designed for this type of use case and is both simpler and more cost effective. Here's an example of a conditional 301 redirect—you can edit as needed.

You can create the function in the **Functions** section of the CloudFront console then attach it to one or more cache behaviors for the distributions where you want this redirect to be used.

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var host = request.headers.host.value;

    if (host === 'www.example.com') {    
        var response = {
            statusCode: 301,
            statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
            headers: { 
                'location': { "value": `https://example.com${request.uri}` } 
            }
        };

        return response;
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: will that help me masking the complete domain name? @Cristian

Comment: A 301 redirect will be returned to the viewer. You will have to explain more specifically what you mean by "masking"

Comment: 301 redirect is fine, i want that with the url masked , i.e, the url in the browser should still show the old url.

Comment: CDNs like CloudFront are reverse proxies, so it already does this at the domain level: your viewers connect to a URL that points to CloudFront and CloudFront internally connects to a different URL (known as your origin) that the viewer doesn't see. I'm still not clear on what you mean by masking: are you trying to **rewrite** the URL path so a request for `/foo` received by CloudFront makes a request of `/some/prefix/foo` (for example) to your origin?

Comment: no such url changes are fine, i am looking for domain redireection while maintaining the same url in users' browser tab. consider i have a new campaign for which i created a shorter domain name(easier for ads and stuff) and now i want this domain to serve a particular page from a CF distribution. normal redirection in DNS settings changes the URL from campaign domain to main website domain. So i was looking for Lambda function to do that.

Comment: anyways i was able to solve it using CF functions. they are very easy to test as well. thanks for the shout-out.